# Get user instead of Userinterface

Tags: symfony

How to get User class instead of Userinterface when i do :

$this->security->getUser()
(Security is Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;)

By Example (and its just an example :), i have this custom function :

```
public function getUser(User $user){
}
```

and when i do that :

```
public function __construct(
        Security $security,
    ) {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

getUser($this->security->getUser());
```

I have a warning :

> getUser expects App\Entity\User, Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface|null given.

Comment: Doesn't your user implement `UserInterface`?

Comment: Yes it is : ```class User implements UserInterface```

Comment: Where do you get this warning? Is this from a static analysis tool like psalm or phpstan?

Comment: Yep, phpstan (and phpstorm too)

Comment: If it's what your editor is telling you, and not what Symfony debugger is telling you, then ignore it. PhpStorm can't resolve it right.

Comment: Phpstan too say that :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a code analysis tool like phpstan or psalm warns you about a type mismatch there are multiple ways to deal with it.

Most likely you want to change your method signature and then handle the cases, the message complains about, e.g. like this:

```php
public function getUser(UserInterface $user = null)
{
    if (null === $user || ! $user instanceof User) {
        // do something about the wrong types, that you might get from getSecurity()->getUser(), e.g. return or throw an exception
        throw Exception(sprintf('Expected App\\Entity\\User, got %s', $user === null ? 'null' : get_class($user)));
    }

    ... your logic
}
```

Now your method accepts both the interface and null that might get in there. You could also do the error handling before calling your getUser method and leave it as is, so instead of just `getUser($this->security->getUser());`:

```php
$temporaryUser = $this->security->getUser();

if (!$temporaryUser instanceof User) {
    throw Exception(sprintf('Expected App\\Entity\\User, got %s', $user === null ? 'null' : get_class($user))); 
}

getUser($temporaryUser);
```

If you are sure that the code will not run into problems, you can also ignore certain error messages by creating a `phpstan.neon` in your project root. See: https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan#ignore-error-messages-with-regular-expressions

Comment: Ok thx, but in my User class i have a getId function (not present in UserInterface) then i cant do that : ``` $user->getId() ```

Comment: i'll ignore this phpstan message (easy solution i know... :D)

Comment: Yes, you can, because after the handling of the special cases you definitely know it's a `App\Entity\User`, so you can use these methods safely.

Answer (score 0):

If `$this->security->getUser()` calls Symfony's core security class to return a user, it will **always** return an object that implements `UserInterface` - that's what the return type of that class defines (either implicitly through a proper return type, or through PHPDoc). This can not be altered by your own application.

To overcome your problem, you own method `getUser` should use this interface as the parameter type to it's argument. In that method, you can check for a more specific class (like: `if($argument instanceof User)`), but not in the method's function signature.

Comment: I tried, but now i cant write $user->getId(), because getId is not in interface

Comment: Well, then you should check whether `$user` is an instance of your `User`. Any code after such a check (that throws an exception or breaks out of that method otherwise) will be of that type, and your IDE should detect this